# Swing application start too slow in JDK 7/8 and OpenSUSE 13.1

Tags: java, swing, opensuse

I'm having trouble to develop swing applications under Oracle JDK 7/8 and OpenSUSE 13.1: They take too much time to start compare to the same app run under JDK 6.

This is my main test code:

```
    final long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

    try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("Set LAF. Milliseconds from start app: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start));

    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            TestSwingJFrame frame = new TestSwingJFrame();
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setTitle("Backup Utilities");
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.setResizable(false);

            System.out.println("Render app. Milliseconds from start app: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start));
        }
    });
```

**TestSwingJFrame.java**: (4 JLabel, 2 JTextField, 4 JButton, 1 JTextArea and no process at all, just UI elements)

```
public TestSwingJFrame() {
    setBounds(100, 100, 360, 575);
    getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    JLabel labelBackup = new JLabel(Constants.UI.TEXT_BACKUPS);
    labelBackup.setBounds(12, 12, 63, 25);
    getContentPane().add(labelBackup);

    JComboBox comboBoxBackups = new JComboBox();
    comboBoxBackups.setBounds(70, 12, 265, 25);
    getContentPane().add(comboBoxBackups);

    JLabel labelDate = new JLabel(Constants.UI.TEXT_DATE);
    labelDate.setBounds(12, 46, 63, 25);
    getContentPane().add(labelDate);

    JTextField textDate = new JTextField();
    textDate.setBounds(70, 46, 120, 25);
    getContentPane().add(textDate);
    textDate.setColumns(10);
    textDate.setEditable(false);

    JLabel labelVer = new JLabel(Constants.UI.TEXT_VERSION);
    labelVer.setBounds(202, 46, 65, 25);
    getContentPane().add(labelVer);

    JTextField textVer = new JTextField();
    textVer.setBounds(266, 46, 70, 25);
    getContentPane().add(textVer);
    textVer.setColumns(10);
    textVer.setEditable(false);

    JButton buttonRequestBK = new JButton(Constants.UI.TEXT_REQUEST_ONLINE);
    buttonRequestBK.setBounds(12, 80, Constants.UI.BUTTON_WIDTH, Constants.UI.BUTTON_HEIGHT);
    getContentPane().add(buttonRequestBK);

    JButton buttonRestoreOnline = new JButton(Constants.UI.TEXT_RESTORE_ONLINE);
    buttonRestoreOnline.setBounds(189, 80, Constants.UI.BUTTON_WIDTH, Constants.UI.BUTTON_HEIGHT);
    buttonRestoreOnline.setEnabled(false);
    getContentPane().add(buttonRestoreOnline);

    JButton buttonBackupLocal = new JButton(Constants.UI.TEXT_BACKUP_LOCAL);
    buttonBackupLocal.setBounds(12, 111, Constants.UI.BUTTON_WIDTH, Constants.UI.BUTTON_HEIGHT);
    getContentPane().add(buttonBackupLocal);

    JButton buttonRestoreLocal = new JButton(Constants.UI.TEXT_RESTORE_LOCAL);
    buttonRestoreLocal.setBounds(189, 112, Constants.UI.BUTTON_WIDTH, Constants.UI.BUTTON_HEIGHT);
    getContentPane().add(buttonRestoreLocal);

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    scrollPane.setBounds(12, 151, 330, 387);
    getContentPane().add(scrollPane);

    JTextArea textLog = new JTextArea();
    textLog.setLineWrap(true);
    textLog.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    scrollPane.setViewportView(textLog);
}
```

[image: Snapshot]

And voila, these pieces of codes take around 17 seconds under JDK 7/8 to render. This is the result for compile and run the app with each JDK:

```
// JDK 8u20
Set LAF. Milliseconds from start app: 17250
Render app. Milliseconds from start app: 17367

// JDK 7u51
Set LAF. Milliseconds from start app: 17271
Render app. Milliseconds from start app: 17375

// JDK 6u45
Set LAF. Milliseconds from start app: 668
Render app. Milliseconds from start app: 931
```

At first, I think there is something wrong with Nimbus LAF, so I remove the code which set LAF, but nothing change at all:

```
// JDK 8u20
Set LAF. Milliseconds from start app: 0
Render app. Milliseconds from start app: 17295

//JDK 7u51
Set LAF. Milliseconds from start app: 0
Render app. Milliseconds from start app: 17263

// JDK 6u45
Set LAF. Milliseconds from start app: 0
Render app. Milliseconds from start app: 245
```

After a little of debugging, I found out most of the starting time of the app (without set LAF) is at this line:

```
frame.setVisible(true);
```

I have tried other Oracle JDK (7u60, 7u65) and the default Open JDK (7u51), but no luck at all. Digging around Google brought no results. 17 seconds to start a simple swing application is really unbearable. Can anyone help me solve this mystery, please!

**EDIT 1 :** I took other tests with Lubuntu, Windows XP and Windows 7:

```
// Lubuntu - JDK 7u10
Set LAF. Milliseconds from start app: 265
Render app. Milliseconds from start app: 392

// Windows XP SP2 - JDK 7u67
Set LAF. Milliseconds from start app: 100
Render app. Milliseconds from start app: 280

//Windows XP SP2 - JDK 7u65
Set LAF. Milliseconds from start app: 562
Render app. Milliseconds from start app: 1061
```

So maybe the problem lies within OpenSUSE 13.1 compatiable with JDK 7/8.

**EDIT 2 :**  As AlexR suggestions, using Eclipse, I've debugged further in Java code and found out this class's method take most of time:

```
Container.validateTree()
```

But without logging, it is impossible to digging further since this is a recursive method.

Comment: Best is to debug and jump into the `setVisible` to see if the newer JVMs do anything fancy beforehand. Also check if (maybe) the new java VMs are fragmented on disk so that loading takes more disk time.

Comment: You say OpenSuse - are you sure it is the Oracle JDK and not OpenJDK through IcedTea? It's not exactly the same.

Comment: @Gimby - Yes I'm sure of which JDK I use to compile and run. I've add them all in Installed JREs list in Eclipse to compare each JDK.

Comment: Eclipse? You didn't mention Eclipse anywhere.

Comment: @Gimby - Sorry I forgot to mention it. But I think it made no diffence, since the Runnable JAR file which I export require the same time to start with java command.

Comment: Then indeed it doesn't matter; another thing to cross off the list of possibilities. Did you try on other systems? Other operating systems too?

Comment: I have edited the post and added other tests with other OSs. Maybe the problem lies within OpenSUSE 13.1 compability with JDK 7/8.